# how to insert values in table2 with reference of table 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to insert values in table2 with reference to table1 using a foreign key.table2 columns are (quesid(primary key/auto-increment), ques,ques_desc). There is another table table1 its primary key is foreign key which is also AUTO INCREMENT. So using that i was trying to insert values.
I have written below query:

```
 insert into users_ques values("What is JAVA","Please SHare the details") 
 from users WHERE quesid = 1;
```

mysql is giving me error at WHERE (where is not valid at this position).
please help me so that i can sucessfully write this query.

Comment: A *from* always needs its best buddy, *select*. Use *select... from...* [See the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use `select` for `insert`

```
insert into users_ques (column1,column2)
select column1,column2 
from users
where quesid = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid MySQL `INSERT` syntax. You either do:

```
INSERT INTO users_ques 
    VALUES ("What is JAVA","Please SHare the details");
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO users_ques 
    SELECT "What is JAVA","Please SHare the details" FROM users WHERE quesid = 1;
```

The way you're doing it now is just combining the two method together.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7bdd74c858ae0ef2730890c0af25d77c)